# Pandas Dataframe interpolate inside with constant value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, fillna

How to make:

```
[In1]:  df = pd.DataFrame({
            'col1': [100, np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
            'col2': [np.nan, 100, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan]})
        df

[Out1]:       col1    col2
        0      100     NaN
        1      NaN     100
        2      NaN     NaN
        3      100     NaN
        4      NaN     NaN
        5      NaN     100
        6      NaN     NaN
```

into:

```
[Out2]:       col1    col2
        0      100     NaN
        1        0     100
        2        0       0
        3      100       0
        4      NaN     NaN
        5      NaN     100
        6      NaN     NaN
```

So basically I want to interpolate/fill NaN's with zero only for the *inside* area and a `limit=2`. Note in `col2` there are three consecutive NaN's in the middle and only two of them are replaced with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build masks to identify the non-NAs, and the inner values (with help of a double [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html)):

```
m = df.notna()
m2 = m.cummax() & m[::-1].cummax()

out = df.fillna(df.mask(m, 0).ffill(limit=2).where(m2))
```

Or with [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

```
m = df.notna()

out = df.fillna(df.mask(m, 0).interpolate(limit=2, limit_area='inside'))

# or if you only have numbers
out = df.fillna(df.mul(0).interpolate(limit=2, limit_area='inside'))
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2
0  100.0    NaN
1    0.0  100.0
2    0.0    0.0
3  100.0    0.0
4    NaN    NaN
5    NaN  100.0
6    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Funny you caught me again!  I found this ingenious: `out = df.fillna(df.mul(0).interpolate(limit=2, limit_area='inside'))`

Comment: @Jingwei I answer a fair share of questions, so it's not unlikely ;)

Answer (score 0):

We could do

```
out = df.ffill(limit=2).mask(df.bfill().isna())
out = out.mask(out.ne(df) & out.notna(),0)
Out[83]: 
    col1   col2
0  100.0    NaN
1    0.0  100.0
2    0.0    0.0
3  100.0    0.0
4    NaN    NaN
5    NaN  100.0
6    NaN    NaN
```